# How to rename bool column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rename

I had `concat` a series to dataframe and here is the list of columns in the `data`.[image: {Picture snap shot]

I have already tried to rename the column `0` using:

```
data.rename(columns= {'0':'BCC'}, inplace = True)
```

But it does not seem to change the name of the column.

Comment: `columns= {0: 'BCC'}`. You can see your column label is the integer `0` not the string `'0'`

Comment: Instead of renaming after, it might be better to set a name on the series before concat'ing, eg: `your_series.name = 'BCC'` then concat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column 0 is **not** a string,'0' is NOT in your index, **0 IS**

Therefore to rename it you have to write:

- data.rename(columns= {**0**:'BCC'}, inplace = True)